# Use "toLowerCase" on an interface's optional attribute

Tags: angular

I'm developping a filtering app in Angular.
I fill a Mat-Table with data and then I set some filters to reduce the amount of displayed projects.

My 'Project' interface has an optional attribute 'location?', which is causing me problems:

```
export interface Project {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  location?: string;
}
```

I add some projects to a constant:

```
export const PROJECTS: Project[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Hey', location: 'London' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Blub', location: 'Rome' },
  { id: 3, name: 'noloc'}
];
```

BUT I have a problem when it comes to filtering:

```
proj.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.locationData.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

The line above returns an error (because 'noloc' has no specified location and I'm therefore trying to apply the function to '*undefined*'):

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

**What's the best way of tackling this?**

For now all I can think of is to replace my interface with a class, and in the constructor make sure that if no location is specified, an empty string is set. But I guess there must be some smarter/nicer way of getting around this.

Comment: `(proj.location || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(....)` will silence the error, but I suspect this is a business logic problem. You shouldn't filter by location for projects that don't have one.

Comment: "You shouldn't filter by location for projects that don't have one": true, I'll try to change my logic

`(proj.location || '')` --> oh, I see :) thank you.

You could write it as an answer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its a simple null check before you apply `toLowerCase()`

`proj && proj.location && proj.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.locationData.toLowerCase()) > -1`